# should I configure my server to use the latest version of PHP?

Tags: php

I'm looking at some things in my cPanel and noticed that my server is using PHP 5.4. Should I change it to PHP 7.1? Is it a good idea to always use the latest version? Is there a big difference in performance between 5.4 and 7x?

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer in general, there are lots of dependencies. For instance, if you use the `mysql` extension, it's not available in PHP 7, so all those scripts need to be updated to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: There is a big difference between the performance in php 5.4 and 7x. I have upgraded one of my servers, but one is still running php 5.6 simply because there is a couple of older websites which code not fully supports php 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test for incompatibilities but PHP 7.1 is much faster, so barring some other reason not to, yes, you should.

Answer (score 2):

if only for security reasons you should, but for resolving common bugs too and [performance](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/php7_infographic)